# The webpage you are viewing is trying to close this window warning in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer

i have a login page and if login is sucessfull,i open a homepage as popup.In IE 6.0,i dont come across a problem but IE.7.0 shows me an alert "The webpage you are viewing is trying to close this window.Do you want to close the window?".When i add the codes to hinder it,now IE 7.0 doesnt give me alert but IE 6.0 gives same problem.How can i solve this problem?

```
Dim strScript As String = "<script language= ""javascript"">window.open('" & Class.cls_LU_PARAMETRE.Deger("START_PAGE") & "','" & Now.ToString("ddMMyyyyHHmmss") & "','resizable=1,width=1015,height=700,left=0,top=0,scrollbars=1,status=1');</script>"
Me.RegisterStartupScript("start", strScript)
```

I add this code to hinder IE 7.0 warning

```
Dim s As String
s = "<script language= ""javascript"">"
s += " {var oMe = window.self;oMe.open('','_self',''); oMe.close();}"
s += " </script>"""
Me.Page.RegisterStartupScript("close", s)

'********************
```

Answer (score 11):

It's a security feature. After all, how would you like it if some website you went to decided to close *your* browser window?

The most correct way to avoid this is to have opened the browser window from javascript. When you do that, the parent window is allowed to close the window without asking the user.

Answer (score 3):

another solution

```
window.opener = "";
window.close();
```

Answer (score 3):

Javascript can close a window if a javascript code opens it.

Open window using javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openWin(url, target, args){
        if(target && args)window.open(url, target, args);
        else if(target)window.open(url, target);
        else window.open(url);
    }
</script>
<a href="javascript:openWin('close.html');">Open window</a>
<a href="close.html" target="_self">Open window that won't close</a>
```

Close window using javascript

```
<a href="javascript:if(window.opener)window.close();">Close window</a>
```

It's simple, and it works in IE6, 7, 8, 9, Chrome, FF, Opera, Safari, etc... I tested it

Answer (score 2):

You can fix this in IE by setting the self.opener property:

```
self.opener = this;
self.close();
```

EDIT: it looks like MS may have fixed this bug (it was always a bug exploit).  Looks like you're out of luck unless you open the window originally yourself, and close it from the same page that opens it.

Comment: Doesn't work for me on Firefox, MSIE7 or Chrome... it would be cool if it did, though. How did you get it to work?

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have IE8, so I can't test it.  I admit this is a really old fix that I haven't used recently.  Perhaps they fixed the bug.

Comment: This works on IE6. Ther other solution of using window.open('','_self','') works on IE7 & IE8. If you just worry about IE, you can have version check code and implement both these solutions.

Answer (score 2):

```
 function openpopup()
 {


     {
         var closeurl = "Default2.aspx";
        var popurl = "FrmUserLoginpage.aspx";
        winpops = window.open(popurl, "HMSAJAX", "toolbar=no,menubar=no, resizable=yes,status=yes,scrollbars=yes");
        window.open('', '_self', '');
        window.close();

    }

}
```