# IE stop message “the web page you are viewing is trying to close the tab.."

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, tabs

I have a script on page that will close the web page but when it does that I am getting this pop up message  “the web page you are viewing is trying to close the tab. Do you want to close this tab?”

I want to suppress this message. I am using IE and done following settings
In IE Tools/Internet Options/Security/(select) Internet Zone> (click) Default
Level.

Or, Internet Options>/Security> (select) Internet Zone> Custom> Scripting>
Active scripting> Enable.
Both the settings didn’t worked for me and I am still getting the message. How can I prevent this?

Comment: I don't think you can turn this off in newer versions of IE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The webpage you are viewing is trying to close this window warning in Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/601465/the-webpage-you-are-viewing-is-trying-to-close-this-window-warning-in-internet-e)

Answer (score 2):

[The webpage you are viewing is trying to close this window warning in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/601465/the-webpage-you-are-viewing-is-trying-to-close-this-window-warning-in-internet-e)

This is a old question and in the awnsers also lays your awnser i quote:

"Javascript can close a window if a javascript code opens it."

Otherwise, it can't. It is just a security feature. I hope i helped :)

Answer (score 0):

There are some interesting workarounds on this question, basically revolving around inserting a `window.open()` somewhere into the sequence.

[Bypass IE "The webpage you are viewing..." pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357410/bypass-ie-the-webpage-you-are-viewing-pop-up)