# Bypassing IE script prompt

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the following javascript  code with a time delay  to close a web page after it has been viewed by the receiver.  The code is working perfectly in Chrome.  However, in IE a popup message is displayed which requires user input to close the page.  How do I modify my code to bypass the user input in IE?

The javascript:

```
<script>
var howLong = 5000;
var t = null;
function closeMe(){
t = setTimeout("window.close()",howLong);
}
</script>
```

I am also using an onLoad statement in the body tag of my html.

```
<body onLoad="closeMe(); self.focus();">
```

Comment: Did you programatically open the window in the first place? (ie with `window.open`)

Comment: How are you calling `closeMe`? An [MCVE](/help/mcve) would be useful.

Comment: Which version of IE?

Comment: What is the content of the user input dialog ?

Comment: @Diptendu Likely to be the usual "this webpage is trying to close the window..." prompt.

Comment: Related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17300705/ie-stop-message-the-web-page-you-are-viewing-is-trying-to-close-the-tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it in my Firefox and it also gave the "This web page is trying to close the window"

I don't think you can do anything about this since this happens because of the browser settings set by the user.

You can try to use

```
var objWin = window.self; 
objWin.open('','_self',''); 
objWin.close();
```

But I think this only works if you open the web page with window.open()